# PHP slow with remote MySQL

Tags: mysql, php

I run ubuntu 18.10 and I've run into issues with a remote database server. I connect using a private network (by IP). The query in bash `mysqlcommand` takes about 9ms, while in the PHP software (eg. PhpMyAdmin) it takes around 1+ second. Having no clue what can be on. I have also added `skip-name-resolve`.

The private network resolves second IP in about 50 ms so I don't see a point in long queries.

Worth noting that the local MySQL ran perfectly before.

Comment: You could use an application profiler such as new relic or datadog to discover what code paths are costing the most amount of time. If you are not seeing latency using the MySQL client on the application server then the issue must lie in PHP, the driver or a combination of things in that region.

Comment: @eroomydna I have an application which has built-in debug tools. It shows that a query with selecting user by id takes 1 second by itself. There are 5 users at all so. Worth noting that it is a fresh installation of PHP and the only thing I have done is enabling certain extensions.

Comment: How long does PHP take to do `SELECT 1` ?  That will be roughly the 'ping' time.